# Filter year and month in laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent

Lets say, I have data as below:

```
2008-09-23
2008-12-23
2020-01-12
2020-02-13
```

I want to filter by following logic which I can only filter year and month. So, the query which I wrote so far is that

```
SELECT *
FROM reports
WHERE
     (YEAR(released_date) >= 2008 AND MONTH(released_date) >= 12);
```

I'm pretty sure that problem because we use **AND** Condition to filter which year from 2008 and month 12. So, how can I handle that logic since data I want to get, it should be from:

```
2008-12-23
2020-01-12
2020-02-13
```

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding from your above example,
You are looking for a query to get data which of year great and equal to 2008 and month great and equal to 12 for the released_date. Try below one

SELECT * FROM reports
WHERE date(released_date) >= 2008-12-01.

Comment: Thank you for answer, But, as you can see below logic. The user will input only year and month to filter. If user like you put below it work fine.

Comment: You simply concate user input Year and month as follows in your query to make it dynamic to make work my above query.
Year + month +1